# transform scipy sparse csr to pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I have used the

```
sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder
```

to transform some data the output is `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`
how can I merge it back into my original dataframe along with the other columns?

I tried to use `pd.concat` but I get

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

Thanks

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If A is `csr_matrix`, you can use [`.toarray()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray) (there's also `.todense()` that produces a `numpy` `matrix`, which is also works for the `DataFrame` constructor):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(A.toarray())
```

You can then use this with `pd.concat()`.

```
A = csr_matrix([[1, 0, 2], [0, 3, 0]])
    
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 2)    2
  (1, 1)    3

<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>

pd.DataFrame(A.todense())

   0  1  2
0  1  0  2
1  0  3  0

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    2 non-null int64
1    2 non-null int64
2    2 non-null int64
```

In version 0.20, `pandas` introduced [sparse data structures](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html#sparse-data-structures), including the [`SparseDataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html#sparsedataframe).

In pandas 1.0, `SparseDataFrame` was [removed](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#migrating):

> In older versions of pandas, the `SparseSeries` and `SparseDataFrame` classes were the preferred way to work with sparse data. With the advent of extension arrays, these subclasses are no longer needed. Their purpose is better served by using a regular Series or DataFrame with sparse values instead.

The [migration](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#migrating) guide shows how to use these new data structures.

For instance, to create a `DataFrame` from a sparse matrix:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

A = csr_matrix([[1, 0, 2], [0, 3, 0]])

df = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(A, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df

   A  B  C
0  1  0  2
1  0  3  0

df.dtypes
A    Sparse[float64, 0]
B    Sparse[float64, 0]
C    Sparse[float64, 0]
dtype: object
```

Alternatively, you can pass sparse matrices to `sklearn` to avoid running out of memory when converting back to `pandas`. Just convert your other data to sparse format by passing a `numpy` `array` to the `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` constructor and use `scipy.sparse.hstack` to combine (see [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)).

Comment: What can I do if my A.toarray() leads to a MemoryError? Is there any way to create the Dataframe without converting it back to a ndarray?

Comment: You may want to take a look at pandas [sparse data structures](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html)

Comment: Is there any chance I can pass my values as labels for the new dataframe? E.g., if the hot encoder had values given from column 'letter' with 'a a b b c a' that my new dataframe would be headed by letter_a, letter_b etc, much like with the dummy-encoder?

Comment: Solved this by passing different arguments to the dummy encoder

Comment: Caveat: if sparse matrix is too big, it will throw memory error since `.toarray()` creates a dense metrix.

Comment: It's more than a caveat. This is completely useless with any sparse matrix that has any business being such.

Comment: @cangrejo how is `.todense()` useless if OP wants to incorporate sparse matrix into DataFrame and how is `SparseDataFrame()` useless as an alternative given memory constraints?

Comment: @Stefan Sparse formats are often employed to store matrices too large to fit in memory.

Comment: @cangrejo OP explicitly intended to combine a sparse matrix with a `DataFrame`. The answer demonstrates how to do this. How is this completely useless, rather than not applicable in case the data does not fit into memory, however frequent these cases may be?

Comment: **Outdated** scince pandas 1.0

Answer (score 10):

## UPDATE for Pandas 1.0+

Per the Pandas [Sparse data structures](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html) documentation, `SparseDataFrame` and `SparseSeries` have been removed.

## Sparse Pandas Dataframes

#### Previous Way

```
pd.SparseDataFrame({"A": [0, 1]})
```

#### New Way

```
pd.DataFrame({"A": pd.arrays.SparseArray([0, 1])})
```

## Working with SciPy sparse `csr_matrix`

#### Previous Way

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
matrix = csr_matrix((3, 4), dtype=np.int8)
df = pd.SparseDataFrame(matrix, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

#### New Way

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

matrix = csr_matrix((3, 4), dtype=np.int8)
df = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(matrix, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df.dtypes
```

**Output:**

```
A    Sparse[int8, 0]
B    Sparse[int8, 0]
C    Sparse[int8, 0]
D    Sparse[int8, 0]
dtype: object
```

---

#### Conversion from Sparse to Dense

```
df.sparse.to_dense()
```

**Output:**

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0
```

---

#### Sparse Properties

```
df.sparse.density
```

**Output:**

```
0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also avoid getting back a sparse matrix in the first place by setting the parameter `sparse` to `False` when creating the Encoder.

The documentation of the [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) states:

> sparse : boolean, default=True
>
> Will return sparse matrix if set True else will return an array.

Then you can again call the DataFrame constructor to transform the numpy array to a DataFrame.

Comment: True, although you might run out of RAM creating a dense matrix with `OneHotEncoder`

Answer (score 0):

**Just Like Scriptator Answer but here is the Code for it**

```
            from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
            from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

            ct=ColumnTransformer(
transformers=[('encoder',OneHotEncoder(sparse=False),[0])],remainder="passthrough")
            g=ct.fit_transform(X)
        
            pd.DataFrame(g)
```

You Pass your Dataset  in X Variable to ct.fit_transform()

the [0] in OneHotEncoder is the index of your categorical independent variable in dataset