# Error : Shape of passed values is (2549950, 1), indices imply (2549950, 13)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm running into the error  `Shape of passed values is (2549950, 1), indices imply (2549950, 13)` when trying to create pandas dataframe out of a One Hot encoded column.

Here's my code snippet.

```
ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(transformed, columns=enc.get_feature_names())
```

The shape of transformed is (2549950, 13) and shape of enc.get_feature_names() is (13,)

Thanks

Comment: I think the shape of your 'transformed' is not what you think.  Your transformed is a single column with a list of 13 values?   Then you will need to expand that list into columns.

Comment: Checked again with the command transformed.shape and the output is (2549950, 13)

Comment: What is the type(transformed)?  The error you are getting indicates a single column.

Comment: type(transformed) is scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

Comment: Use toarray()  or todense()... See this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36968458/6361531

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(transformed)

ohe.df.columns = enc.get_feature_names()
```

Comment: Tried this, I get the error : ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 13 elements

Comment: transformed matrix is in sparse format as you commented above, change it to `pd.DataFrame` by  using [this method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix.html)